# Navigate from on UIView to another UIVew in view based application?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I created a View based application in which i want to navigate from one view to another on a button click but i cannot find the right method??
is it only possible in navigation based application??
i tried addsubview method but still not working??

what is the right method to accomplish this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching: (UIApplication*) application {
    [_window addSubview: [_firstView view]];
    [_window makeKeyAndVisible];
}

// This method is on AppDelegate   
- (void) navigateToSecondView {
    [[_firstView view] removeFromSuperview];
    [_window addSubview: [_secondView view]];
}
```

But, you must implement an animation because this raw changes doesn't have a default one.